# Plot segments along axis using start and end points in python (like a stacked bar graph)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I'm trying to plot segments along an axis using a PANDAS dataframe that contains their start and end numbers, and I was wondering if it's possible to do this in python. Here's an exmaple of what the data looks like:

```
ID  start   end
A   94      97
B   20      22
B   22      35
A   63      92
```

and [an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUxMJ.png) of how I want the plot to look.

The dataframe contains start and end points for multiple segments and I want to plot them along the axis, kind of like a horizontal stacked bar graph (barh) in matplotlib, but I have no idea how to do it. I'm also looking for a way to color each segment based on the ID (e.g. segments classified as B are red and A are blue).

I tried using `df.plot.barh(stacked=True)` but I can't get it to include multiple segments in the same bar. Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: Please do not post images of your data. Copy and paste the text into the question.

Comment: @QuangHoang got it, just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `plt.bar`:

```
colors = df.ID.map({'A':'C0', 'B': 'C1'})

plt.bar([1]*len(df), df.end-df.start, bottom=df.start, color=colors,
        edgecolor='k')
```

Output:

[image]

Or if you want a horizontal bar chart:

```
plt.barh([1]*len(df), df.end-df.start, 
         left=df.start, color=colors,
         edgecolor='k')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! One followup question, I'm having trouble modifying the axes. I want to remove the vertical axes labels completely and set the horizontal axes going from 0 to 107, is that possible in this format?

Comment: Also, do you know if there's any way to vertically shrink the plot?

Comment: Play with `ylim`, `xlim`, and `figsize`. You can look them up.